# Como mudar o background de um checkbox apenas com CSS?

Tags: html5, css3

CSS em **width** e **heigth** surtem efeito, pq no **background-color** não?

```css
input{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
input:checked{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Bom amigo, algumas propriedades são se aplicam a todos os elementos. Como por exemplo o **CheckBox** não contém a propriedade background-color.

Comment: Certo, mas, como então tem checbox como este do materialize https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html, eles criam uma div?

Comment: Bom o checkbox ele não tem a propriedade background-color, porém ele tem a propriedade background-image.. Pelo que eu vi.. a imagem é meio que alterada quando vc marca com checked com um algum tipo de efeito slowly que deixa tão interessante !! Pegue duas imagens... de checkbox no google img, e aplique no checkbox.

Comment: @LeAndrade você chegou a inspecionar o objeto para ver como é feito? Parecido com o que o @MauroAlexandre sugeriu, o *materializecss* estiliza um `<label>` que tem o `checkbox` dentro

Comment: Opa Ricardo, inspecionei sim, mas não entendi, como é feito não.

Comment: O que você não entendeu, @LeAndrade ?

Comment: O checkbox do materialize mudar de cor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dito pelos colegas cada `user-agente` de cada browser tem seu "estilo padrão" para alguns componentes HTML, Entre eles vc pode reparar facilmente que alguns `inputs` como `radio`, `checkbox`, `select`, etc no FireFox é diferente do do Chrome que é diferente do Safari etc, Como vc pode ver nessa imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*texto grifado*No caso do Checkbox vc pode resolver isso tirando todas as propriedades default do `user-agente` usando `all:unset` no elemento.

Veja no elemento abaixo que eu estilizei o `input checkbox` da forma que vc queria apenas limpando os estilos *default*.

```css
input{
    all: unset;
    border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input:checked{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Atualmente com o CSS3 você pode customizar um `checkbox`, porém vale ressaltar que não há um modo certo de se fazer, há na verdade vários métodos, alguns `cross-browser` e outros não.

### Label

O método mais comum, utilizado em `frameworks` conhecidos, é utilizar `label` para incorporar o `checkbox`.

```html
<label class="chk">
    <input type="checkbox" name="exemplo" />
    <span></span>
</label>
```

Nesse exemplo (padrão), o input fica dentro do `checkbox` e o `span` serve como "âncora" para o estilo.

Aplicando o CSS, já é possivel ter alguns resultados.

```css
.chk input {
    display: none;
}

.chk span {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.chk input:checked + span {
    background-color: #c03;
}
```

```html
<label class="chk">
    <input type="checkbox" name="exemplo" />
    <span></span>
</label>
```

Você pode utilizar imagens no lugar de color, o bacana de utilizar este método é que você pode controlar totalmente o span

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container-label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #424242;
  font-weight: 400;

}

.container-label input{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;

}

.checkmark{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.container-label input:checked ~ .checkmark{
  background-color: #002D32;
  border: none;
}

.checkmark::after{
  display: none;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.container-label .checkmark::after{
  content: '';
 left: 4px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 5px;
 height: 9px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 border-right: 3px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;

}

.container-label input:checked ~ .checkmark::after{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="container-label">
                    One
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">

                    <span class="checkmark"></span>

                  </label>
```